# Inputs inside Jquery UI Dialog not being sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, post

I have many dialog box in my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function paydetail(windID) { 
        $(".dialog").dialog("destroy"); 
        var dlg = $("#dialog"+windID).dialog({ 
            resizable: false, 
            width: 490, 
            modal: true, 
            buttons: { 
                "OK": function() { 
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                }
            } 
        }); 

        dlg.parent().appendTo($("#domains" + windID)); 
        return false; 
    } 
</script>
```

Html look that, multiple forms with unique name and id (e.g. name="domains_list5" id="domains5"):

```
<form action="/domains_list/" method="POST" name="domains_list{$domain.id}" id="domains{$domain.id}">
    <tr>
        <td width="50" class="datetime acenter">
            <a href="#" onclick="paydetail('{$domain.id}'); return false;"><img src="{$site_root}{$css_js_path}/images/domen_info.png" /></a>
            <div id="dialog{$domain.id}" class="dialog dialog-infopay hide" title="info">
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">ID:&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <input type="text" value="{$domain.webmaster_id}" name="domain_webmaster_id[{$domain.id}]" style="width: 50px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="90">
            <input style="margin: 20px auto 15px;" type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript: document.domains_list{$domain.id}.submit();" value="Обновить" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

After submit one of form, I dont get POST data from modal in this form. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery ui dialog box detaches the contents and places it at the end of the page.  This effectively removes it from the form.
The only thing you can do is have hidden inputs that get the contents of any of the dialog inputs.